# Google Analytics Goals - How to combine destination and event goals types?

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to set up a goal in Google Analytics, basically an ecommerce goal - which will say how many users searched and viewed the product and how many added to cart, and then how many checked out.
But my data is in such a way that - to create such a goal I need to combine both destination goal type and event goal type.

For example, searching a product and viewing it , have different URLs -- So this can be set up at destination goal type,
But Add to cart - is an GA event that will trigger and the page URL doesn't change.

So to record this scenario as a Goal what should I do ? Is there a way to combine destination and event goal types together in a single goal ?
Or can it be done in another way ?